# How do we express set theoretic extensionality in Mathematica for instance I want it to see {2,1} as equal to {1,2)

Tags: sets

I think the title pretty much covers it

Comment: I think we need  not create a new type name set,just use function and operator  such `Union` ,`Intersection` etc. act on the list

Comment: Look in the help under "guide/OperationsOnSets"

Comment: And the proof that {1,2}={1,2} can be found where in the help guide?

Answer (score 3):

To add to the comments, you can easily define your own container for sets like this:

```
ClearAll[set]
SetAttributes[set, Orderless];
s : set[___] /; ! DuplicateFreeQ[Unevaluated @ s] := DeleteDuplicates[Unevaluated @ s];

set[1, 2] === set[2, 1] === set[1, 1, 2]
```

> True

Just be aware that the built-in function [Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) has nothing to do with set theory.

Comment: Their needs to be a closer parallel to the axiom of extensionality.  I don't want it to know that {1,2}={2,1}, I want to be able to prove from extensionality things like {1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1}={1,2}  but there is an unlimited different presentation for even just a finite set...

Comment: I think you may need to elaborate your question then, because it's not clear to me what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I want to write the axiom of extensionality in Mathematica.